# Postgresql - How can I execute a view definition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I want to "test" the execution of a postgres view sql. Something like

```
select exec(select pg_get_viewdef('schema.materialized_view_name', true))
```

(that isn't working)

I'm working with materialized views. The materialized views are selecting data from a foreign data wrapper table and I want to "test" the sql code before refreshing the view. The underlying data source schema may have changed and I want to ensure that I don't end up with no data in my materialized view. I'd rather have outdated cached data than no data.

So in summary:

1. Test to make sure the sql query from the materialized view returns a valid result (count > 0)
2. Run materialized view to update the data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_viewdef(view_to_test regclass) RETURNS boolean
   LANGUAGE sql SET transaction_read_only = on AS
$$DECLARE
   dummy integer;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'SELECT 42 FROM (%s) LIMIT 0',
              pg_get_viewdef(view_to_test)
           ) INTO dummy;
   RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
END;$$;
```

Beware that the `LIMIT 0` is no protection against a long execution time.

Comment: Maybe: `SELECT 42 FROM (%s) WHERE 1=0 ...` ? instead of LIMIT ?

Comment: @wildplasser Would that offer any advantage?

Comment: Okay, I'll give this a go tomorrow. Thanks for the responses! Just curious, what is the `SELECT 42 FROM` ... do?